# M13checkbox inside UITableView cell fires when click on cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

as the title I'm can put M13checkbox inside the cell and all of it works fine, the only problem is when I click outside the checkbox, it also reacts, so the checkbox will be changing it's state 
Can anyone help?
I'm assuming it's something about UIGestureRecognizer
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it my simply disable tableview allowselection

```
self.yourtableview.allowsSelection = false
```

for anyone who needs to do what I was tring to do